# Is it possible to maintain member variables value across all the threads in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I want to maintain some member variable values in Multi-Threading application. I have single object of the class across the application. Now, i don't want any thread will re-initialize all the member level variables for it's execution. I used ThreadLocal but it creates a Dictionary which holds all the threads and there respective member variable values. I don't want to use such kind of thing.

Comment: readonly (C# Reference) https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/readonly

Comment: I think ThreadLocal would be the _opposite_ of what you want.

Comment: Use a static `Lazy<T>`: it will be initialized once and any thread that hits`.Value` will get the same instance.

Comment: @RomanRyzhiy readonly will not work in my case. Because I'm setting it inside one method. i can't set it while initializing. That setter will be called once per user.

Comment: @AmanAgarawal "That setter will be called once per user" means that every user has his own instance?

Comment: Please add code. It will make it much easier to come up with an answer. 5 lines of code is worth a 1000 words.

Comment: Use `static` class or, better, [singleton](https://csharpindepth.com/Articles/Singleton) (see last version with `Lazy<T>`).